# subscript out of bounds error in document-term matrix

Tags: r, list, tm

I am doing text mining in following data, but I get following error at the end

```
Error in `[.simple_triplet_matrix`(dtm, 1:10, 1:10) : 
  subscript out of bounds
```

can you help me address this error.

```
library(rvest)  
library(tm)
library(snowball)
wiki_url <- read_html("https://wiki.socr.umich.edu/index.php/SOCR_Data_2011_US_JobsRanking")    
html_nodes(wiki_url, "#content")    
job <- html_table(html_nodes(wiki_url, "table")[[1]])   
head(job)   

#'  
#' ## Step 1: make a VCorpus object 
#'  
#'  
jobCorpus<-VCorpus(VectorSource(job[, 10])) 
#'  
#'  
#' ## Step 2: clean the VCorpus object  
#'  
#'  
jobCorpus<-tm_map(jobCorpus, tolower)   
for(j in seq(jobCorpus)){   
  jobCorpus[[j]] <- gsub("_", " ", jobCorpus[[j]])  
}   
#   
#   
jobCorpus<-tm_map(jobCorpus, removeWords, stopwords("english")) 
jobCorpus<-tm_map(jobCorpus, removePunctuation) 
jobCorpus<-tm_map(jobCorpus, stripWhitespace)   
jobCorpus<-tm_map(jobCorpus, PlainTextDocument) 
jobCorpus<-tm_map(jobCorpus, stemDocument)  
#
#   
# build document-term matrix    
#   
# Term Document Matrix (TDM) objects (`tm::DocumentTermMatrix`) contain a sparse term-document matrix or document-term matrix and attribute weights of the matrix.  
#   
# First make sure that we got a clean VCorpus object    
#   
jobCorpus[[1]]$content  
#   
#   
# Then we can start to build the DTM and reassign labels to the `Docs`. 

    
dtm<-DocumentTermMatrix(jobCorpus)  
dtm 
dtm$dimnames$Docs<-as.character(1:200)  
inspect(dtm[1:10, 1:10]) ###<-- error happens from here 

#' Let's subset the `dtm` into top 30 jobs and bottom 100 jobs. 
    
    
dtm_top30<-dtm[1:30, ]  
dtm_bot100<-dtm[101:200, ]
```

Answer (score 1):

2 issues. First, the use of `tolower` in this way strips the corpus of too much info. Second, you should use `DataframeSource` instead of `VectorSource`. With `VectorSource` as you use it, you only load 1 document with 200 lines, instead of 200 documents with a line each.

Code below works, I start from where you have created the job data.frame:

```
#you need the columns doc_id and text, you could rename 2 columns in job as well. 
# instead of doc_id as a doc_# you could also take the job title column
job_for_corpus <- data.frame(doc_id = paste0("doc_", job$Index),
                             text = job$Description, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

# no need for loop, just use gsub on data.frame column
job_for_corpus$text <- gsub("_", " ", job_for_corpus$text)

# create corpus
jobCorpus <- VCorpus(DataframeSource(job_for_corpus))

# clean text
jobCorpus <- tm_map(jobCorpus, content_transformer(tolower))   
jobCorpus <- tm_map(jobCorpus, removeWords, stopwords("english")) 
jobCorpus <- tm_map(jobCorpus, removePunctuation) 
jobCorpus <- tm_map(jobCorpus, stripWhitespace)   
jobCorpus <- tm_map(jobCorpus, stemDocument)  


jobCorpus[[1]]$content  
[1] "research design develop maintain softwar system along hardwar develop medic scientif industri purpos"

# create document term matrix
dtm <- DocumentTermMatrix(jobCorpus)  

inspect(dtm[1:10, 1:10]) 
<<DocumentTermMatrix (documents: 10, terms: 10)>>
Non-/sparse entries: 2/98
Sparsity           : 98%
Maximal term length: 7
Weighting          : term frequency (tf)
Sample             :
        Terms
Docs     16wheel abnorm access accid accord account accur achiev act activ
  doc_1        0      0      0     0      0       0     0      0   0     0
  doc_10       0      0      0     0      0       0     0      0   0     0
  doc_2        0      0      0     0      0       0     0      0   0     0
  doc_3        0      0      0     1      0       0     0      0   0     0
  doc_4        0      0      0     0      0       0     0      0   0     0
  doc_5        0      0      0     0      0       0     0      0   0     0
  doc_6        0      0      0     0      0       0     0      0   0     0
  doc_7        0      0      0     0      0       0     0      0   0     0
  doc_8        0      0      0     0      1       0     0      0   0     0
  doc_9        0      0      0     0      0       0     0      0   0     0

# rest of your code
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively to the answer offered by @phiver, after "head(job)" convert the jobs to "list"....

jobs <- as.list(job$Description)
jobCorpus <- VCorpus(VectorSource(jobs))

....